# HTML file having trouble calling a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Trying to learn how libraries work in HTML.

In my HTML file, I am trying to make use of functions from a JavaScript file that is located in the same folder as the HTML file. I would like the function to tell the HTML to print a simple message to the screen, so I know I've made some progress, but alas, I have no clue what I'm doing. This is as far as I got with online sources and a textbook I have on hand.

Here's what my HTML looks like so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- project9.html -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Function</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Test()
        </script>
    </head>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the test.js file, located in the same folder as the HTML file:

```
function Test(){
    return ' test '
}
```

I'm overlooking something super simple, aren't I?

Comment: remove function before your call to Test()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to CALL a function, you just need to refer to that function's name (and any arguments but in this case that isn't relevant) and not the word `function`.

Also you are RETURNING the string, not doing anything with it. This will at least just alert it.

```js
function Test(){
    return ' test '
}

alert(Test())
```

Comment: Some people like to use semi-colons in JS but it isn't necessary

Comment: @berkobienb, I have a javacript minifier that I use, so I prefer to use them. But you are correct they aren't needed to terminate lines.

Comment: You could also just use `console.log(Test())` rather than `alert()`

Comment: That worked perfectly fine. Knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: @berkobienb, yes but if the OP is new I didn't want them to implement the code and have no idea why they can't see anything.

Comment: @imvain2 you did a great job. Nice work. I'm just picky haha

Comment: @berkobienb I suppose I could ask. I gave that console.log a try and indeed didn't know why I couldn't see anything. It's a log, so is that being stored somewhere?

Comment: @ConnerMcClellan, your browser has a web developer/console area. I believe some times it is accessible via the F12 button, otherwise its accessible in one of the browser's drop down menus.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. That makes more sense. Alright. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

To modify HTML content on the screen, you'd use get a reference to the element and then use `innerHTML`

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <script src="./index.js"/> <!-- just import the file -->
  </body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
function test() {
  var p = document.getElementById("test");
  p.innerHTML = "test";
}
test(); //notice the function call
```